# C# TableCell Format Text or Render HTML

Tags: c#, html, text, subscript, tablecell

Hard-coding a table in which a cell displays R<sub>max</sub> with "max" as a subscript.

```
TableCell c = new TableCell();
c.Text = "R&lt;sub&gt;max&lt;/sub&gt;";
```

But the result is rendered R< sub >max< /sub > (without the whitespaces - sorry, crappy get-round to stop it from rendering in this post)

Right text, wrong rendering. Also, I'd like to use CSS to control fonts etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
c.Text = "R<sub>max</sub>"
```

UPDATE:

```
string html = "R&lt;sub&gt;max&lt;/sub&gt;";
html = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(html);
Response.Write(html);
```

Comment: Yes, but I have a complication in that I'm reading the text from an XML file - hence the substitution of "&lt;" for "<" and "&gt;" for ">".

Comment: ... or I could change the XML. Any suggestions?